# Sometimes I see this JSONDecodeError and sometimes I don't

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to fetch data from an API using `Requests` in python.
Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it throws this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I can't figure out what's the problem here, can anyone help me out.
[Here's the API](https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY)

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'symbol':'NIFTY'}
r = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices', params = payload, headers = headers).json()

print(r.keys())
print(r['records'])
```

Comment: Check the response code before parsing!

Comment: The API link is dead.

Comment: Maake sure you save the response, perhaps before trying to decode it as JSON, then you can examne it - it’s not JSON and by examining it you’ll probably find it’s HTML, maybe it includes text that gives some reason for the non-JSON response. Maybe you have to use `try/except JSONDecodeError` around the decoding to catch the exception.

Comment: @martineau It is not dead.

Comment: @barny Thanks that's a good solution but is that the only reason why sometimes I get this error and sometimes I don't.

Comment: Add the exception trapping and log it. The code basically works, and as it’s so small it looks pretty clear that reasons it might fail are nothing to do with the code itself, i.e. problems with the internet or the remote web server. No amount of asking here is going to clarify, diagnose or fix that - all you can do is make your code robust and by for example adding logging at least give your self information to help you understand different failures afterwards.

Comment: @barny Thanks for such a clear reply, It really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to set cookies to make this website work.

To do so with `requests`, you need to use a [`session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

```py
import requests

s = requests.session()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
s.get("https://www.nseindia.com", headers=headers)  # set cookies

payload = {'symbol':'NIFTY'}
r = s.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices', params=payload, headers=headers)
r.json()  # will display content
```

Comment: I did try your solution but 1 out of 10 times it is showing me the same error, How are we using the session in api request

Comment: It should work everytime, but it depends on the server-side logic of this website. When I tried again with this method, it worked everytime, so I assumed it was about cookies set. Try changing UA, using one more realistic.